# How to loop the files in a directory, and do some tasks based on each filename?

Tags: maven, loops

There is a `properties` directory in my project:

```
properties
    - project_dev.properties
    - project_test.properties
    - project_prod.properties
    - project_other.properties
```

Which defines some different values for different enviroments. And there is also a `template` directory, which contains some configuration file templates with placeholders.

What I want to do is to loop all the files in `properties`, and combine each one to the `template` directory to generate the final configuration files, which are under different directories based the file name.

So it will be:

```
target
   - configurations
       - dev
            - ... some files
       - test
            - ... some files
       - prod
            - ... some files
       - other
            - ... some files
```

What I'm doing now is to use the `maven-resources-plugin`, and define several `execution`s for each of the files, and hard-coded the names.

It looks like:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <!--- for dev ---->
            <execution>
                <id>dev-filter</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf/dev</outputDirectory>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/conf/template</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>channel/*</include>
                            <include>rule-config/*</include>
                            <include>server/*.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>${basedir}/properties/project_dev.properties</filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!--- for prod ---->
            <execution>
                <id>prod-filter</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf/prod</outputDirectory>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/conf/template</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>channel/*</include>
                            <include>rule-config/*</include>
                            <include>server/*.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>${basedir}/properties/project_prod.properties</filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!--- for test --->
             ...
```

You can see I'm copying the `execution` block for each file, so there will be many duplicated code with small differences.

I wonder is there any solution to make things simpler? I tried to find a way to loop the files under `properties` and do the `filter` task for each of them, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I think it is possible to implement the same using <if> (https://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) inside a <for> (https://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution for such purposes is the [Iterator-maven-plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>executor</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <items>
          <item>dev</item>
          <item>test</item>
          <item>prod</item>
        </items>

        <pluginExecutors>
          <pluginExecutor>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf/@item@</outputDirectory>
                 <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                 <resources>
                   <resource>
                     <directory>${basedir}/conf/template</directory>
                     <filtering>true</filtering>
                     <includes>
                        <include>channel/*</include>
                        <include>rule-config/*</include>
                        <include>server/*.properties</include>
                      </includes>
                     </resource>
                   </resources>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>${basedir}/properties/project_@item@.properties</filter>
                    </filters>
               </configuration>
          </pluginExecutor>
        </pluginExecutors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The documentation contains also an [example](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/executor-property.html) which is very similar to your needs.

Apart from that i would suggest to use the following properties in your pom file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

than you don't need to define the encoding separately for the maven-resources-plugin.